# How to get data from web page by python?

Tags: python, web

On webpage http://baza.ue.poznan.pl/ there are two inputs for surname and name of workers and search button. I want get all workers data automatically by python script. I don't have any experience with webdev. Could you give me any advice how I can do it in the best way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](how-to-ask). Could you give us the code that you have, what you're expecting, and what you're seeing instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at python request library for http requests:

http://docs.python-requests.org/

To parse the html response checkout:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

When you enter surname and name in the webpage and press enter,

the page send a post request to http://baza.ue.poznan.pl/index.php with form-data conataining these details(check out the network tab in developer tools in browser)

The response this page gets is html which is displayed by your browser.

You can parse this response using BeautifulSoup to obtain worker's data